# QGIS Web Client Theme Switcher Issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

Theme switcher from git version seems broken too. I believe that I got the right configuration with GISProjectListing.js as projects are correctly displayed but map switching fails on "Loading Map". Note that I could not even get it to work with the test data provided...

Is there proper documentation on configuration? There is absolutely nothing in logs. Alternatively is there a stable version of the software as what is in git seems really untested.

Platform is Ubuntu 14.04.

Update:

Looking at working sites, I saw that the projectpath variable was set to "". This setting works in my case but still I have to manually adjust the map as bounding box is not taken from project neither from startExtent variable. Any idea what could be wrong with the map bounding box? GlobalOptions.js has project with EPSG 3857 to allow definition of bounding box bringing user to the right area from QWC main page but all map layers use EPSG 4326. In GISProject.js all "visibleLayers" are with EPSG 4326. Could it be the reason for the problem, should one visible layer use EPSG 3857?